# Internet persistently disconnecting on hp pavilion p6-2335ea (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Tags: 20.04, internet, hp

I am having problems with my internet connection on a recent (~ 2 weeks ago) install of ubuntu 20.04. When I boot up my computer, the internet connects just fine, but after a while, it will disconnect and often struggle to regain connection. I have tried WiFi and Ethernet, but both have similar problems. It may be the hardware, but I wanted to rule out ubuntu first. This is the output of `sudo lshw -class network`:

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 08
       serial: 78:e3:b5:b2:4c:68
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=192.168.1.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:fe900000-fe93ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: wlp5s0
       version: 00
       serial: 74:e5:43:e8:61:0a
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=5.4.0-42-generic firmware=0.40 ip=192.168.1.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 memory:fe800000-fe80ffff
```

Comment: You have to give us more information... like snippets from the log files... /etc/log/syslog. However, your ethernet interface is only connecting at 100Mb/s, so you've probably got a cabling problem there.

Comment: Having a look in syslog I found the following lines:

Comment: Your last comment was incomplete. Edit your question and add data there, not into the comments please. Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me EXACTLY the make/model # of your computer or motherboard. What did you do about the ethernet cabling problem?